# Change default dir for docker images (using docker snap)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, haskell-snap-framework

On my app, docker compose images on a default location : data/dev/xvda1

I added a new storage on AWS and mount it on my server :

```
/dev/xvdf         20961280   53920  20907360   1% 
/data/dev/xvda1   8065444 2400580   5648480  30%
```

How can I tell docker to compose images on it ?

I already tried to edit `/var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json`, which is :

```
{
    "log-level": "error",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"

}
```

but docker fails to start and compose.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-root` option to change the location.

```
{
    "log-level": "error",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2",
    "data-root": "/dev/xvdf",
}
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file

Comment: When I do and restart docker, then compose, I have the following error :
`ERROR : Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run docker-machine start default` (this error appears also when the json is invalid)